# Why else part is executed even the first case when condition is true in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, function, runtime-error, substring, case

```
SELECT
    CASE                      
       WHEN CHARINDEX('$','$2,500') > 0              
           THEN
               CASE 
                   WHEN CHARINDEX(' ','$2,500', CHARINDEX('$','$2,500') + 2) > 0  
                       THEN SUBSTRING('$2,500', CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500'), CHARINDEX(' ', '$2,500', CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500') + 2) - CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500'))              
                       ELSE SUBSTRING('$2,500', CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500'), LEN('$2,500') - CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500') + 1)           
               END                
           ELSE '$2,500'                      
    END
```

I have a variable of type `varchar` which may contain some random words after the number so what I am doing is if the variable contains space after the number (space may also be there after $ so we do not have to consider that) then take substring from the $ sign till the space after the number.

But in the above case, there is no space so it should go into if part which is basically going but it is giving the invalid length parameter passed error.

```
SELECT
    CASE                      
        WHEN CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500') > 0              
            THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', '$2,500', CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500') + 2) > 0  
                        THEN SUBSTRING('$2,500', CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500'), CHARINDEX(' ', '$2,500', CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500') + 2) - CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500'))              
                        ELSE SUBSTRING('$2,500', CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500'), LEN('$2,500') - CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500') + 1) 
                END                
            ELSE '$2,500'                      
    END
```

Comment: please format your code correctly

Comment: "I have a variable of varchar which may contain" - no you don't but perhaps you might create one which more effectively illustrates your need.

Comment: As it stands now `WHEN  CHARINDEX('$','$2,500') > 0` will always be true as `SELECT CHARINDEX('$','$2,500')` returns 1 - try it

Comment: "The starting position returned is 1-based, not 0-based." ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks hence why we need the variable to best reproduce your issue perhaps

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a bad parameter into the [substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current) function, even though that function doesn't end up in your execution path. It still must meet the requirements for the function.

From the documentation (link above), the `length` parameter *"Is a positive integer or bigint expression that specifies how many characters of the expression will be returned. If length is negative, an error is generated and the statement is terminated."*

You can see the issue here:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=0 THEN SUBSTRING('$2,500',1,-5) ELSE 'Success' END
```

> Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function.

This throws the same error, even though the `WHEN` path of the case expression is not viable.

Because you can't pass a negative value to the `length` parameter of the `substring()` function, you will need to account for this in your sql using something like the following:

```
THEN SUBSTRING('$2,500', CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500'), GREATEST(CHARINDEX(' ', '$2,500', CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500') + 2) - CHARINDEX('$', '$2,500'), 0))
```

Working [dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Xtz4VIq)